Run once in loop
i am making a signup and login like game but i need that one part of the code runs only once the sign up one and if the user in the login part types incorrect login or password it like skips the signup part and asks you to write your password and login i just need to skip the part of the sign up after happening once.
        while (fail == 2)
        {
            if (code1 <= 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("https//:youtube.com/sign-in/");
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.WriteLine("Create your Account.");
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.WriteLine("Please set your login: ");
                var name = Console.ReadLine();
                Thread.Sleep(1500);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Please set your password: ");
                var password = Console.ReadLine();
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int RN = rnd.Next(1, 3);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Creating Account");
                Thread.Sleep(800);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Creating Account.");
                Thread.Sleep(800);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Creating Account..");
                Thread.Sleep(800);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Creating Account...");
                Thread.Sleep(800);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Creating Account");
                Thread.Sleep(800);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Creating Account.");
                Thread.Sleep(800);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Creating Account..");
                Thread.Sleep(800);
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Creating Account...");
                Thread.Sleep(800);
                Console.Clear();
                Thread.Sleep(800);
                if (RN == 1)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine("Successfully created Account.");
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to login to your account? (y/n)");
                    var input = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Clear();
                    code1 += 2;
                    if (code1 >= 5)
                    {
                        if (input == "y" || input == "Y" || input == "yes" || input == "YES" || input == "Yes")
                        {
                            
                            Console.WriteLine("Write down your login:");
                            var login = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("Write down your password.");
                            var password2 = Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.Clear();
                            fail = 4;
                            if (fail == 4)
                            {
                                fail = 3;
                                if (login == name)
                                {
                                    if (password2 == password)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Successfully logged in, Have Fun!");
                                        Thread.Sleep(3000);
                                        Console.Clear();
                                        Console.WriteLine("Exiting");
                                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                                        Console.Clear();
                                        Console.WriteLine("Exiting.");
                                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                                        Console.Clear();
                                        Console.WriteLine("Exiting..");
                                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                                        Console.Clear();
                                        Console.WriteLine("Exiting...");
                                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                                        Environment.Exit(0);
                                    }
                                }
                                if (password2 != password || login != name)
                                {
                                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect login or password.");
                                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                                    Console.Clear();
                                    
                                }
                            }
                            else if (input == "N" || input == "n" || input == "No" || input == "NO" || input == "no")

                                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("Exiting");
                            Thread.Sleep(500);
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("Exiting.");
                            Thread.Sleep(500);
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("Exiting..");
                            Thread.Sleep(500);
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("Exiting...");
                            Thread.Sleep(500);
                            Environment.Exit(0);
                        }
                    }
                else if (RN == 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("There was an Error with creating your Account, Try again");
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    Console.Clear();
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


So remember that you signed up in a variable and surround the code to be skipped with an if (...)?

You should focus on writing object oriented code, so create classes to encapsulate functionality. On that way you keep your code readable and avoid spaghetti code like this.

i am new and yeah dont even know how to do that i just wrote things that i know and yeah and what is object oriented code ? and what classes im really sorry

Please, do put not everything into a single huge loop: extract methods like bool CreateAccount(), bool LoginToAccount(), bool LoginOrCreate()

State machine with adjustable steps time. Synchronously called method, which performs animation . -> .. -> ... at the end of given string. Better with async/await.

Are you asking how to keep data between multiple runs of your program? If so, a simple way is to use User settings. But there are plenty of options, from simple serialization to databases.

"i am new and ... what is object oriented code ? and what classes" - if you are that new, I'd recommend an introductory course of your preferred type. There are written courses, videos, hands-on tutorials ... whatever is your "type of learning". And no wonder: even from Microsoft: Learn C# - "Free courses, tutorials, videos, and more about learning the programming language C#"

BTW it's https:// not https//: :D

i do not understand what you are talking about it is not me it is you it is very difficult to decipher the text when you write chaotically and use like no punctuation at all.
